# ImportError: Could not import settings 'wequest.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named wequest.settings

Tags: python, django

I am new to python / django. I was following a tutorial to make a test virtualenv for testing tinymce settings. By mistake I changed DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE setting. I have checked the sys.path, making sure that the paths for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set. However, this setting project name of 'wequest' is not the name of the current project.  I copied over all the files into a new virtualenv called wequest1. In all the places I research i made sure that DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE was set to mysite.settings.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
'mysite.settings'
>>>
```

Where is the mysite variable set that is giving my 'wequest' not 'wequest1'. 
Any other help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to search for 'wequest' in your project ? ie. grep -r wequest /path/to/project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Delete all .pyc files**: `find /path/to/project -name '*pyc' -delete`
2. **Search for files that still refer to wequest**: `grep -r wequest /path/to/project`
3. **Fix these files** B)

Comment: Searching through files that refer to wequest found I had put some additional settings that were pointing os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'wequest.settings' in an init.py file in one of my APPS... Need to not do stupid things like that. Thanks